# How to check if there is no validation error exist in webpage using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to check if all form fields are filled on click a button & if valid then i am trying to add a check an alert using jquery.

```
 jQuery("button#btn_place_order").click(function(event){
    jQuery("form").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('ok');
      }
   });
});
```

This is what i have tried but its not working, i just want to check if all fields are ok valid & filled & there is no form related error then just console or alert to check. Webpage has two or more html forms. Is their any way we can check using jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you will have to prevent the default behavior of a form submit. Afterwards add a event listener to your button and check for validation of each input. (whatever that means for you). Is this what you wanted?

```js
var el = document.getElementById("form");
el.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, true);
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(){
  let valid = true;
  [...document.getElementById("form").elements].forEach((input) => {
  if(input.value.length == 0){
   valid = false;
  }
});
  if(valid) alert("valid");
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="TEST" id="test">
</form>
<button class="button" name="Send" value="Send" id="btn">Check</button>
```